# Double signal send with command timeout

Tags: c, signals

I am currently working on a project where I need to manage signals.
I am currently using this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void gest_sig_int(int signo) {
    write(1, "I receive a signal\n", 19);
}

int     main(void) {
    struct sigaction s;

    s.sa_handler = gest_sig_int;
    s.sa_flags = 0;
    sigemptyset(&s.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGINT , &s, NULL);
    while (1);
    return (0);
}
```

I compile with

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

If I execute the code and use **CTRL + C** the programme display

```
./test
^CI receive a signal
```

Which is exactly the result I want !

But when I am trying to do the same thing with the **timeout** command my programme receive the signal twice

```
timeout -s INT 2 ./test
I receive a signal
I receive a signal
```

I don't know if it's come from my programme or the command **timeout**

Thanks for reading !

Comment: `printf` is not async-signal-safe.  Calling it from a signal handler produces undefined behavior.

Comment: Even if I use write instead of printf the output is exactly the same

Comment: Then updating the question to present code with well-defined behavior would improve it.  But the larger message here is don't call `printf` from a signal handler.  Don't take the idea that it is ok, even if it seems to have the result you expect in any given case.  I have seen cases where it fails, and it is a poor strategy to open yourself up to such failures.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information I edited my post

Comment: Can't reproduce this. `timeout` only sends one signal and I only see one line of output from the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I am trying to do the same thing with the **timeout** command my
> programme receive the signal twice

I can reproduce your issue with the `timeout` command included in GNU coreutils 8.25.

> I don't know if it's come from my programme or the command **timeout**

I don't see any reason to think it's your program, and I can observe different behavior if I use a different variation on the `timeout` command:

```
> timeout -k 1 -s INT 2 ./test
I receive a signal
Killed
>
```

The `-k 1` instructs `timeout` to send a SIGKILL to the child if it does not terminate within one second of receiving the first signal.  With this, the test program's signal handler (which is registered only for `SIGINT`) fires only once, no matter how long a delay is specified for the kill timeout.

The observed behavior of this version of `timeout` when a `-k` option is not specified seems to be to send a second signal of the same type if the child does not terminate within a sub-second delay after the first signal.  Indeed, I take this to be established by your experiment, though I do not find it documented.

Comment: Thanks ! You are right ! It's not from my function the timeout command send is apparently sending an other sigint if the programme doesn't exit after the first signal.